# Is it possible to use Lagrange multiplier to solve this problem?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I am asked to find the minimum and maximum value to the function $f(x,y) = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2+4}$ on the the circle $x^2 + y^2 ≤ 4$. When I try to use Lagrange multiplier I get some very nasty equations.

Comment: Do you mean $x^2 + y^2 = 4$? If you actually mean the whole circle, then see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49473/lagrange-multipliers-with-inequality-constraints).

Comment: I mean the whole circle. I am not forced to use Lagrange multiplier, so I am curious to how one should go about solving this.

Comment: Lagrange multiplier method is  for $\text{equalities}$ only. Keep that in mind.

Comment: I guess you can use Lagrange multipliers (Karush-Kuhn-Tucker theorem). But you could alternatively first look for boundary extrema and then for interior extrema. On the boundary you have $x^2+y^2=4$, that is, you need to maximize/minimize $y/8$ on the circle. In the interior you don't need a Lagrange multiplier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $f$ is continuous everywhere, so it will have extrema on the (compact) disk. You can check the interior for critical points $(\nabla f = 0)$, and then (if necessary) the boundary with Lagrange multipliers.

The equation $\nabla f = 0$ has solutions $(x, y) = (0, \pm 2)$. Extrema have to occur at critical points. Where are these points located in relation to the circle?

Comment: These points satisfies x^2+y^2 ≤ 4 which means that they are on the boundary of the disk? So there are no max/min on the interior?

Comment: Right, so Lagrange multipliers are unnecessary. The function takes on its extrema on the circle already. (Or rather, that's where the extrema _could_ happen. The other answers show that this is in fact where they happen.)

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you determine the points at wich the gradient of $f$ is $0$; these are $(0,\pm2)$. The hessian at $(0,2)$ is negative-definite, and the hessian at $(0,-2)$ is positive-definite.

At the boundary of the disk, $f(x,y)=\frac y8$. So, the minimum there is $-\frac12$ and the maximum is $\frac12$.

Since $f(0,2)=\frac14$ and $f(0,-2)=-\frac14$, the maximum of $f$ is $\frac12$ and the minimum is $-\frac12$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Should it be f(x,y) = y/8?

Comment: @StudentMaths Right you are! I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

Change variables to

$$
x = \rho \cos\theta\\
y = \rho \sin \theta
$$

and then

$$
L(\rho,\theta,\epsilon) = \frac{\rho\sin\theta}{\rho^2+4}+\lambda( 2-\rho-\epsilon^2)
$$

Here $\epsilon$ is a slach variable to avoid the inequality.

The solutions are

$$
\rho = 0 \rightarrow x = y = 0\\
\rho = 2, \theta = \pm \pi/2
$$